# To find behaviour of series whose nth term is given

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is multiple choice question from assignment i am doing . i well know all tests for convergence testing of infinite series but im having problem with way the series is defined 
Givn series whose nth term is given by

$a_n$ = {1/n : when n is a perfet square }

```
  ={1/n^{2} when n is not a perfect square}
```

Then $a_n$ is

a) convergent

b)divergent

c)divergent as lim as n goes to infinity n$a_n$ is not equal to zero

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\eqalign{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
  &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}
  +\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\cr
  &=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi^4}{90}+\frac{\pi^2}6\cr
  &=\frac{\pi^2}3-\frac{\pi^4}{90}\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Can you please explain ? .thanks

Comment: I added up all the terms $1/n^2$.  Then I subtracted the ones you don't want.  Then I added the terms you are using to replace the ones you don't want.  The expressions with $\pi$ are well known formulae, you can look them up online.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The sequence of partial sums is increasing and bounded above by twice the sum of the reciprocals of the squares. So our series converges.

Comment: well im'sorry can you pls elaborate . thanks

Comment: Add up the terms up to $N$. We get the contribution $\sum \frac{1}{i^2}$ from the non-squares, where $i\le N$, and the contribution $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$ from the squares, where $k\le $\sqrt{N}$. Both contributions are bounded above.